# 'NSString?' does not have a member 'componentsSeparatedByString'

Tags: ios, swift, weather

Creating weather app from udemy course. I'm wondering if there is something wrong with (`<span class=\"phrase\">`)
 which I got from the page source of the website 
http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/Medellin/forecasts/latest

[image]

Comment: The `?` in the text of the error message is critical. It's saying that you are trying to call a method on a `String?` (i.e. a `String` optional). You have to unwrap this optional before you use it, as Leonardo describes below. In the future, please make sure to include the precise text of the error message (as well as your source code) in the question. The image can be supporting information about the behavior you are experiencing, but as images are not searchable, you really should include the text of the error and code in the question, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message means that you need to unwrap your string result before using the method componentsSeparatedByString. you can force unwrap it using an exclamation mark "!" at the end:

```
let myArray = urlContent!.componentsSeparatedByString("yourString")
```

or using "if let"

```
if let urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
    let myArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("yourString ")
}
```

Note: you can't cast the result from componentsSeparatedByString to NSString. It returns a string array.

Comment: Only use forced unwrapping `!` if the result could never, ever, under any circumstances be nil because if it is ever nil the app will crash. Generally if it is an option it is possible for it to be nil.